# Can I make a struct or class conform to a generic protocol multiple times?

Tags: swift, generics, cqrs, swift-protocols

Let's say I have these protocols:

```
protocol Command {}

protocol CommandHandler
{
    associatedtype T: Command
    func handle(command: T) throws
}
```

I would like to make a command-handler that can handle multiple commands, like so:

```
class InventoryCommandHandler: CommandHandler
{
    func handle(command: AddItemCommand) {
        // do something
    }

    func handle(command: RemoveItemCommand) {
        // do something
    }

    func handle(command: SomeOtherCommand) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But when I try that it says that InventoryCommandHandler is not conforming to the CommandHandler protocol. Is there a way to do this at all?

Answer (score 2):

You should defined `CommandHandler` like this

```
protocol CommandHandler {
    func handle(command: Command) throws
}
```

Now given these 3 commands

```
struct AddItemCommand: Command { }
struct RemoveItemCommand: Command { }
struct SomeOtherCommand: Command { }
```

You can create your `InventoryCommandHandler`

```
class InventoryCommandHandler: CommandHandler {
    func handle(command: Command) throws {
        switch command {
        case let add as AddItemCommand: handle(command: add)
        case let remove as RemoveItemCommand: handle(command: remove)
        case let other as SomeOtherCommand: handle(command: other)
        default: break
        }
    }

    private func handle(command: AddItemCommand) {
        // do something
    }

    private func handle(command: RemoveItemCommand) {
        // do something
    }

    private func handle(command: SomeOtherCommand) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with trying to implement a command-handler that can handle multiple commands with your current solution is

Your protocol defines one function `handle(command:)` but you have declared three in `InventoryCommandHandler` - this would throw an error even if you took away your current 'protocol conformance' error because you are essentially writing the same method in `InvertoryCommandHandler` three times. Even though `AddItemCommand`, `RemoveItemCommand` and `SomeOtherCommand` might conform to the same protocol (`Command`), it would be too ambiguous to the compiler to figure out the difference as it would view all three as essentially the same function.

The recommended way would be to define a function for each command in your `InventoryCommandHandler` protocol.

```
protocol CommandHandler
{
    func handle(command: AddItemCommand) throws
    func handle(command: RemoveItemCommand) throws
    func handle(command: SomeOtherCommand) throws

    //add more as more commands made
}
```

There are many solutions to your problem and this is just one of them.